System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception.' in WinUI 3 project
I need to rebuild the WinForm project in WinUI 3 to redesign the interface in xaml.
The project contains a class named BaslerPylonCamera which uses Basler.Pylon.dll as one of the references.
BaslerPylonCamera in two projects are mostly the same except for the variables related to the interface.
The WinForm project works fine. But if I try to run the WinUI 3 project, it occurs error.

Here are the codes:
MainWindow.xaml.cs in WinUI 3 project
using DeviceBalserGigeCCD;
using Emgu.CV;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Dispatching;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using ShareAPI;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace CRHandlerCCDTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty window that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ACCD ccd = new BaslerPylonCamera(); // The error occured here
        // ACCD is an abstract class for CCD
        
        /* Some parameters */

        public MainWindow()
        {            
            this.InitializeComponent();

            //...
        }

        /* Other methods */
    }
}


Exceptions in Visual Studio

Original/First error

The error occurred at the beginning.

System.TypeInitializationException
HResult=0x80131534
Message=The type initializer for '' threw an exception.
Source=DeviceBaslerGigeCCD
StackTrace:
at DeviceBalserGigeCCD.BaslerPylonCamera..ctor() in \CRHandlerCCDTest_240723\DeviceBaslerGigeCCD\BaslerPylonCamera.cs:line 69
at CRHandlerCCDTest.MainWindow..ctor() in \CRHandlerCCDTest_240723\CRHandlerCCDTest\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 33
at CRHandlerCCDTest.App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args) in \CRHandlerCCDTest_240723\CRHandlerCCDTest\App.xaml.cs:line 44
at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IApplicationOverrides.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IApplicationOverrides.Do_Abi_OnLaunched_0(IntPtr thisPtr, IntPtr args)
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
Inner Exception 1:
ModuleLoadException: The C++ module failed to load during process initialization.
Inner Exception 2:
SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.


Error(s) I found out/appeared later

I saw the comment of this question, so I click Debug--> Exceptions and check ON "C++ Exceptions" checkboxes, rebuilt, and run the project.
Then I got this error before the original one appeared:

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCDCE4FABC in CRHandlerCCD_240729.exe:
Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location
0x0000000000000000.


Exceptions in WinDbg
I checked my Windows Event Log and here are the exceptions:

Error - App crashed when try to ignore the error and run the project in VS



System

Provider
[ Name]  Application Error
[ Guid]  {a0e9b465-b939-57d7-b27d-95d8e925ff57}
EventID 1000
Version 0
Level 2
Task 100
Opcode 0
Keywords 0x8000000000000000

TimeCreated
[ SystemTime]  2024-07-31T05:26:08.7636580Z
EventRecordID 335071
Correlation

Execution
[ ProcessID]  42500
[ ThreadID]  14784
Channel Application
Computer

Security
[ UserID]  S-1-5-21-178552597-1107329665-3621315115-1857







EventData
AppName CRHandlerCCD_240729.exe
AppVersion 1.0.0.0
AppTimeStamp 661f0000
ModuleName Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll
ModuleVersion 3.1.5.0
ModuleTimeStamp 73620e9d
ExceptionCode c000027b
FaultingOffset 00000000004051c5
ProcessId 0x44a0
ProcessCreationTime 0x1dae30a232106af
AppPath \CRHandlerCCD_240729\CRHandlerCCD_240729\bin\x64\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win-x64\AppX\CRHandlerCCD_240729.exe
ModulePath C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.5_5001.178.1908.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll
IntegratorReportId 656ff57b-608f-4d84-8450-d7012cc74221
PackageFullName 417b56fc-e3df-430a-939a-76afb6c4b4a3_1.0.0.0_x64__vr48ag13rqvjp
PackageRelativeAppId App




Error - Try to run the .exe

This blog (in Mandarin) gave me the idea of trying directly run the .exe in \CRHandlerCCD_240723\CRHandlerCCD_240723\bin\x64\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64 to get exceptions.
I do get an exception, but it isn't because of Basler.Pylon.dll:

Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll' or one of its dependencies:
The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" /> 
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID> 
    <Version>0</Version> 
    <Level>2</Level> 
    <Task>0</Task> 
    <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-08-02T03:16:50.3923471Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>339030</EventRecordID> 
    <Correlation /> 
    <Execution ProcessID="42416" ThreadID="0" /> 
    <Channel>Application</Channel> 
    <Computer></Computer> 
    <Security /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application: CRHandlerCCD_240723.exe CoreCLR Version: 6.0.3024.21525 .NET Version: 6.0.30 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E) at CRHandlerCCD_240723.Program.XamlCheckProcessRequirements() at CRHandlerCCD_240723.Program.Main(String[] args) in \CRHandlerCCD_240723\CRHandlerCCD_240723\obj\x64\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\App.g.i.cs:line 29</Data> 
    </EventData>
</Event>


I searched for some solutions:
The solution for TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '' threw an exception
WPF Type initialization Exception in C#
TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code
clear and rebuild the project, but nothing worked.
How to fix this error?

Edit
I tried to simplified my code and project to isolate the issue.
Then I encountered two different issues depending on the platform target.

x86 (32-bit): System.IO.FileNotFoundException


System.IO.FileNotFoundException
HResult=0x80070002
Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Basler.Pylon, Version=1.2.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e389355f398382ab'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Source=240805_LightCodeDebugProject
StackTrace: at _240805_LightCodeDebugProject.BaslerPylonCamera..ctor() in \240805_LightCodeDebugProject\240805_LightCodeDebugProject\BalserPylonCamera.cs:line 63
at _240805_LightCodeDebugProject.MainWindow..ctor() in \240805_LightCodeDebugProject\240805_LightCodeDebugProject\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 31
at _240805_LightCodeDebugProject.App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args) in \240805_LightCodeDebugProject\240805_LightCodeDebugProject\App.xaml.cs:line 44
at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IApplicationOverrides.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IApplicationOverrides.Do_Abi_OnLaunched_0(IntPtr
thisPtr, IntPtr args)


x64 (64-bit): System.TypeInitializationException

This is the original issue.

The Basler.Pylon.dll is in the output directory for both x86 and x64.
When targeting x86, the DLL is not found. When targeting x64, the type initialization fails.

Clearly some exception occurs in Basler.Pylon.dll, but it is not delivered to your code, and is reported as unhandled exception.  It is not clear what is wrong from the information provided.

Thank you @Nick for telling me that.
I tried built the project in X86, X64, still didn't work.
Are there some ways to get the exception from Basler.Pylon.dll in Visual Studio?
Or I need to use other tools to help me with this error?

You cannot get it in VS.  Perhaps you can check Windows Event Log.  Some exceptions are reported there.

I ignored the error and ran the project, and then it crashed.
Then I checked my Windows Event Log and found some exceptions (Added in my post!).
My Windows Event Log didn't show exceptions when the error occurred.
Does that mean I still can't get exceptions from the error?

Stowed Exception C000027B might help.

Also, try catching the exception directly. For example, try { var camera = new BaslerPylonCamera(); } catch (Exception exception) { }.

I rewrote it like this: Declare ACCD ccd  first, then in public MainWindow() is try { ccd = new BalserPylonCamera(); }  catch ( Exception ex ) { Console.WriteLine( ex.Message ) }  But the error still occurred at the ccd = new BalserPylonCamera(); line. ex.Message is "The type initializer for '' threw an exception.""

@AndrewKeepCoding Thank you for providing me with this tool and explanation. I'm a newbie using WinDbg, so it takes some time for me to learn to use it and collect info. For now I only found out that WinDbg stops after the line that occurred error in Visual Studio.

Since adding breakpoints before/at the error line would cause WinDbg stop debugging (It says Unable to insert breakpoint 3 at 000001d19fdc012b, Win32 error 0n299  "Completes only part of the ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory  requirements" bp3 at 000001d19fdc012b failed), I still cannot catch the exception directly. Also, the exception shown in WinDbg is the error due to the original error.

I guess you should consider getting support from the lib provider.

I will consider it, thanks. I got a new exception today(Added to the post). The weird thing is this WinUI 3 project could run before I replaced the .dll (It was also Balser.Pylon.dll.) So I'm baffled...

Use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  Its trace shows your program searching for the missing DLL and failing to find it.

Hi Hans, thanks for your advice. It shows that the process did load image, and the path led to Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll and Basler.Pylon.dll separately. Since the results are SUCCESS, does this mean the process loads the DLL successfully?
